# How to get all cookies from CookieManager android ?

Tags: android, cookies

For `Android CookieManager`  class there is a method -- `getCookie(String url)`.
For this we need to know correct url.
Is there a way to get all cookies in `CookieManager` and get the urls .
some thing like `getCookies` ??
This is just to double check if i am giving anything wrong in my `url` for `getCookie(String url)` call.
I am not getting the cookie when i call the same.
I am passing complete `IP address` here in url. Something like this : `"xx.x.x.x"`

Thanks
Mia

Comment: i am trying to extract cookie from webview after succesful login- its simple -- String cookieString = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("xx.x.x.x);

Answer (score 7):

I used the CookieManager with the java.net package in my Android Application and it works like a charm. Here is a code snippet :

```
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.util.List;

private class MyCookieManager
{       
    private CookieManager mCookieManager = null;

    MyCookieManager() {
        mCookieManager = new CookieManager();
        mCookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(mCookieManager);
    }

    private List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
        if(mCookieManager == null)
            return null;
        else
            return mCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    }

    public void clearCookies() {
        if(mCookieManager != null)
            mCookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
    } 

    public boolean isCookieManagerEmpty() {
        if(mCookieManager == null)
            return true;
        else 
            return mCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().isEmpty();
    }


    public String getCookieValue() {
        String cookieValue = new String();

        if(!isCookieManagerEmpty()) {
            for (HttpCookie eachCookie : getCookies())
                cookieValue = cookieValue + String.format("%s=%s; ", eachCookie.getName(), eachCookie.getValue());
        }

        return cookieValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: @stan 
when i want to use getCookieValue() ,i have to create object of MyCookieManager class and constructer will be called and every time new instant of CookieManager will be generated with no cookie saved. How can i retrieve cookie from default CookieManager where i previously stored cookie ?

Comment: @HarshalBhatt, it's supposed that you create and keep a single instance of `MyCookieManager` in your application. Anyway, all instances should normally return the same set of cookies from default cookie store (or a custom store if your'll change the source to provide specific store in `CookieManager` constructor).

Answer (score -1):

You can [use reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html#fields) to see the cookie map. It's called mCookieMap in 4.0.3 (and probably in earlier releases as well). The type is Map>.

This isn't a great way of doing it because you'll risk breaking on different devices or OS versions if they don't use mCookieMap, but CookieManager doesn't offer a public way of knowing which URLs it's visited.

Comment: The cookies in 4.2.2 are stored natively, so this will not work: http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/webkit/CookieManagerClassic.java

Comment: I knew it'd break eventually. :-)